# Keep  'em (functions) in the same place in memory

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll, assembly

I am building a C++ application for Windows that I'm going to hook with a DLL (in assembly code). But I'm having problems reverse engineering the console application I made.

I want to keep the function addresses in the same place, but they keep moving in memory each time I edit and rebuild the DLL.

Is there a way to keep them in the same place? And is there a way to keep the backing storage of a variable (e.g. `int`) in the same spot (memory address)?

Comment: The only way to stop functions or global variables from moving is to stop editing.  Address Space Layout Randomization keeps them moving after that, designed to stop you from doing what you want to do.

Comment: Note that you can usually turn off ASLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to hardcode addresses in assembly language.

You can just link with the DLL as usual.

If this doesn't work for you, post code and exact problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. I've never heard about compiler/linker with this feature.